# give number format to a selection depending on value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a small-helpfull macro for my day to day with Excel spreadshits, this macro is supposed to give format to cells depending of the value.

```
Sub decimals()
    ScreenUpdating = False
    If Selection.Value > 0.99999999 Then
        Selection.NumberFormat = "#,#00"
    Else
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End If
End Sub
```

the code works for one cell selection but not with a range, I suppose it's missing some loop? like for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a multi-cell selection, then the `Selection.Value` comparison won't work.

Perhaps try something like this:

```
Sub Decimals()
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub

    Dim rng As Range        
    For Each rng In Selection
        If IsNumeric(rng.Value) Then
            If rng.Value > 0.99999999 Then
                rng.NumberFormat = "#,#00"
            Else
                rng.NumberFormat = "0.00"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```